# Postgres Join query not able to find where the query is spending time from explain statement

Tags: postgresql, optimization

From the below explain statement I am not sure where the time is spent during the Postgres query execution, One of the tables after applying the filters just has 0 rows in that shouldn't the join be faster, not sure where the query spends most of the time, also is there a way to rewrite this query in an optimised way.

```
SELECT "commission"."period_start_date","commission"."period_end_date","commission"."payee_email_id","commission"."commission_plan_id","commission"."criteria_id","commission"."line_item_id","commission"."tier_id","commission"."original_tier_id",SUM("commission"."amount") "amount",CONCAT('Commission') "record_type",MAX("commission"."secondary_kd") "secondary_kd",MAX("commission"."knowledge_begin_date") "knowledge_begin_date",MAX("unique_comm_lock"."max_locked_knowledge_date") "locked_kd" FROM "commission" JOIN (SELECT "client_id","payee_email_id","period_start_date","period_end_date",MAX("locked_knowledge_date") "max_locked_knowledge_date" FROM "commission_lock" WHERE "client_id"=31 AND NOT "is_deleted" AND "knowledge_end_date" IS NULL AND "is_locked"=true GROUP BY "client_id","payee_email_id","period_start_date","period_end_date") "unique_comm_lock" ON "commission"."client_id"="unique_comm_lock"."client_id" AND NOT "commission"."is_deleted" AND "commission"."payee_email_id"="unique_comm_lock"."payee_email_id" AND "commission"."knowledge_begin_date"<="unique_comm_lock"."max_locked_knowledge_date" AND ("commission"."knowledge_end_date">"unique_comm_lock"."max_locked_knowledge_date" OR "commission"."knowledge_end_date" IS NULL) AND "commission"."period_start_date"="unique_comm_lock"."period_start_date" AND "commission"."period_end_date"="unique_comm_lock"."period_end_date" WHERE "commission"."client_id"=31 AND "commission"."knowledge_begin_date">='2023-09-03T03:16:56.633166+00:00' GROUP BY "commission"."period_start_date","commission"."period_end_date","commission"."payee_email_id","commission"."commission_plan_id","commission"."criteria_id","commission"."line_item_id","commission"."tier_id","commission"."original_tier_id"

Explain 
GroupAggregate  (cost=7269.33..7269.38 rows=1 width=307) (actual time=63641.414..63641.416 rows=0 loops=1)
      Group Key: commission.period_start_date, commission.period_end_date, commission.payee_email_id, commission.commission_plan_id, commission.criteria_id, commission.line_item_id, commission.tier_id, commission.original_tier_id
      ->  Sort  (cost=7269.33..7269.33 rows=1 width=246) (actual time=63641.413..63641.414 rows=0 loops=1)
            Sort Key: commission.period_start_date, commission.period_end_date, commission.payee_email_id, commission.commission_plan_id, commission.criteria_id, commission.line_item_id, commission.tier_id, commission.original_tier_id
            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1651.85..7269.32 rows=1 width=246) (actual time=63641.383..63641.384 rows=0 loops=1)
                  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1651.15..1657.50 rows=635 width=54) (actual time=12.537..14.365 rows=728 loops=1)
                        Group Key: commission_lock.client_id, commission_lock.payee_email_id, commission_lock.period_start_date, commission_lock.period_end_date
                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on commission_lock  (cost=42.51..1642.88 rows=662 width=54) (actual time=11.570..11.938 rows=728 loops=1)
                              Recheck Cond: ((client_id = 31) AND (knowledge_end_date IS NULL))
                              Filter: ((NOT is_deleted) AND is_locked)
                              Heap Blocks: exact=61
                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cl_ked_il_li_idx  (cost=0.00..42.35 rows=662 width=0) (actual time=11.545..11.545 rows=865 loops=1)
                                    Index Cond: ((client_id = 31) AND (is_deleted = false) AND (knowledge_end_date IS NULL) AND (is_locked = true))
                  ->  Index Scan using comm_pei_ped_psd_kbd_ked_idx on commission  (cost=0.69..8.82 rows=1 width=250) (actual time=87.396..87.396 rows=0 loops=728)
                        Index Cond: ((client_id = 31) AND (is_deleted = false) AND ((payee_email_id)::text = (commission_lock.payee_email_id)::text) AND (period_end_date = commission_lock.period_end_date) AND (period_start_date = commission_lock.period_start_date) AND (knowledge_begin_date <= (max(commission_lock.locked_knowledge_date))) AND (knowledge_begin_date >= '2023-09-03 03:16:56.633166+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                        Filter: ((knowledge_end_date > (max(commission_lock.locked_knowledge_date))) OR (knowledge_end_date IS NULL))
```

Comment: The aggregation of the `max_locked_knowledge_date` subquery is relatively fast (14ms), but then it spends most of the time with 728 index accesses of `comm_pei_ped_psd_kbd_ked_idx` where each of them appears to take 87ms.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, It makes sense just wondering if the number of rows in one table is 0, shouldn't the join be completed faster?

Comment: The number of rows in the table is not 0. The number of rows matching the join condition is.

Comment: yea you are right, I rewrote the query which enforced hash join and improved performance. Thanks.

Comment: Mind [writing an answer](/help/self-answer) then? I'm curious what you did change

Comment: I did the 'group by' operation before performing the join which reduced the number of rows to be joined and improved the performance.